# How to check if directory exists at particular path programmatically in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, relative-path, absolute-path

Please tell me how to

1. Get the current working directory's absolute path
2. If this is the absolute path
   /Users/iphone/Documents/Archive

   how to convert this path to relative path?
3. How to check if directory exists at patricular path programmatically in Objective-C and if it doesn't exist how to create it programmatically? i need to do this using relative path.

Thank You.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main source of information is the Apple [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672)

From there or subtopics you get information for your questions.

1) NSFileManager [currentDirectoryPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_21)

3) NSFileManager [fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_29)

Comment: -1, I don't like this, I can read the documentation as well, but stack overflow and google is faster for easy questions like this.

Comment: This doesn't actually provide an answer, it just says "Go look at these volatile documents somewhere else". How about explaining best practices, or pros and cons of different approaches? And yes, people from the future are self righteous.